# Como posso usar o comando fopen?

Tags: c++

Sempre que tento usar o comando fopen o Visual Studio me retorna um erro dizendo que tal comando é inseguro, e que devo usar o fopen_s, mas no caso não sei que rumo tomar com o fopen_s.

Comment: Já que está programando em C++ não seria melhor usar um *stream*?

Comment: Mas como eu encaixaria uma stream em um KeyLogger?

Comment: Também nunca consegui usar o VS fica enchendo a paciência com isso

Comment: Pois é, mas eu entendo o VS, fopen pode ser manipulado, por isso o fopen_s, porem as estruturas do código mudam e eu não sei prosseguir

Comment: Apenas como dica, utilizar `fopen_s` é desaconcelhado por questões de portabilidade. A melhor solução seria mesmo o que o @Maniero disse e seguir com uma solução de streams que é o normal para C++. Fica mais uma dica "não complique algo simples".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação da função](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx), o trecho de código usando `fopen`:

```
fp = fopen(filename, mode);
```

pode ser reescrito como

```
errno_t error_code = fopen_s(&fp, filename, mode);
```

em que `error_code` é igual a `0` se a operação for bem sucedida ou contém um código de erro se a operação falhar. Note que o primeiro argumento de `fopen_s` é `FILE**`, ou seja, um ponteiro para um ponteiro. Por isso é necessário passar o endereço de `fp` como `&fp`.

Com exceção do tratamento de possíveis erros que agora deve considerar o valor de `error_code`, o resto do código deve funcionar da mesma maneira que funcionaria se fosse usada a função `fopen`.

### Edição:

Percebi que não respondi diretamente a sua pergunta. Se você realmente desejar usar `fopen` (por razões de portabilidade, por exemplo), defina a macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` antes de incluir `stdio.h`:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!